# How we can get dimensions of .ai file in php

Tags: php, imagemagick

I create one page for image conversion.I want to convert image from .ai to .jpg.But issue is that how can i get dimensions(width and height) of AI file.I alredy tried getimagesize() but it's not working, it give me blank response.

Here is my php code

```
if($fileType == 'psd' || $fileType == 'ai' || $fileType == 'eps' || $fileType == 'pdf'){
        $source_file_name = get_file_name(basename($_FILES["sfile"]["name"]));



        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sfile"]["tmp_name"],SOURCE_UPLOAD_PATH.$source_file_name)) {

            //get dimensions of image
            $dimensions = getimagesize(SOURCE_UPLOAD_PATH.$source_file_name);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($dimensions);exit;
```

Comment: Post some codes please.

Comment: please do comment, but don't downgrade question.i am here to support if you have any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readimage($imagePath);
if ($fileType == "psd" || $fileType == "ai"){
    $image->setIteratorIndex(0);
}
$dimensions = $image->getImageGeometry();
$width = $dimensions['width'];
$height = $dimensions['height'];

echo "Your image is $width by $height pixels";
```

Comment: Hey Danon,thanks for answer,but i want to set dimension of converted file same as source file dimension.So i need it before to go for convert it.

Comment: Why can't you just run this code before converting? Code I pasted is to be used **only** to get width and height.